# ContextMenuStrip not showing on the first time of being right clicked

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

I've added a contextmenustrip programmatically through the extension of panel along with some other stuff,
It is being set into the panel's contextmenu through the panel's constructor.

The first time I right click does not work and then it will after the first time always.

I have tried also to put the constructor of the contextmenustrip and the assigning of it to the panel's context menu in other places such as *Load* and the form's constructor and even in a timer with a flag, All produced the same result..

EDIT:(Some code as requested(as it is and cut to important points))

```
class FiniteAutomationController : System.Windows.Forms.Panel
{
    public FiniteAutomationController()
        : base()
    {
    this.ContextMenuStrip = (cms = new ContextMenuStrip());
    }
    public ContextMenuStrip cms;
}
```

EDIT:(Per blaze_125's request, some more code)

```
//at form designer initializecomponents after Controller(FiniteAutomationController)'s initialization

this.Controller.cms.Opening += new System.ComponentModel.CancelEventHandler(this.cms_Load);

//at form code class
    static State contextS = null;
    static Action contextA = null;
    private void cms_Load(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        Controller.cms.Items.Clear();

        if ((contextS = FiniteAutomationData.GetStateFrom(mouseX, mouseY)) != null) // Rclick States
        {
            Controller.cms.Items.Add("Delete"); Controller.cms.Items[0].Click += new EventHandler(cms_DeleteState);
            Controller.cms.Items.Add("Rename"); Controller.cms.Items[1].Click += new EventHandler(cms_RenameState);
            Controller.cms.Items.Add((contextS.final ? '\u2714' : ' ') + " Final"); Controller.cms.Items[2].Click += new EventHandler(cms_Final);
            Controller.cms.Items.Add((contextS.initial ? '\u2714' : ' ') + " Initial"); Controller.cms.Items[3].Click += new EventHandler(cms_Initial);
            Controller.cms.Items.Add("Trap"); Controller.cms.Items[4].Click += new EventHandler(cms_Trap);
            if (!contextS.error.Equals(""))
            {
                Controller.cms.Items.Add("Error: " + contextS.error); 
                Controller.cms.Items[5].Enabled = false;
            }
        }
        else if((contextA = FiniteAutomationData.GetActionFrom(mouseX,mouseY)) != null) // Rclick Action
        {
            Controller.cms.Items.Add("Delete"); Controller.cms.Items[0].Click += new EventHandler(cms_DeleteAction);
        }
        else // Rclick null
        {
            Controller.cms.Items.Add("Add State"); Controller.cms.Items[0].Click += new EventHandler(cms_AddState);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show us some code.

Comment: Where's the click event and so on? We need a better picture of your problem. Code gives us that picture that's worth a thousand words. As much as you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Throughout the last 3 days I've managed to find a solution which I think is a really bad one, but a solution still..

What I did is used the MouseDown Event of the Controller and using a flag,
Showed the context menu on the first time using it's *Show(Point)* method.

The show method placed the menu a bit off and I settled on "*new Point(e.X,e.Y+45)*" to place it correctly which still I don't like that I'm doing as it seems really unprofessional..

Thanks anyways I guess..

Answer (score 4):

I found (well, with the help of DotPeek) that when using a blank `ContextMenuStrip` for a `Control`'s `ContextMenuStrip` property so that you can add the items dynamically the code in `System.Windows.Forms` actually sets the `Cancel` property of the `CancelEventArgs` that are passed to the `Opening` handler to `true` because the context menu at first is empty and contains no items.

On subsequent calls, even if the first thing you do in the `Opening` handler is clear all items, the `Cancel` property will be set to `false`.

So my fix to make sure the context menu shows up at all times (including the first one) was to always set the `CancelEventArgs`' `Cancel` property to `true` or `false` and not (falsely) relying on it to be initialized to `false` anyway...

Comment: I wish I could upvote this more than once. This one was driving me nuts. WinForms is full of silly stuff like this.

Answer (score 0):

For my case, I need to show the context menu by clicking on ToolStripButton. It is not shown for the first click. I managed this problem in this way

```
    void _TsiMenu_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AdjustableMenu.Show(this, this.PointToClient(Cursor.Position), ToolStripDropDownDirection.Default);
        Application.DoEvents();
        if (AdjustableMenu.Visible == false)
            AdjustableMenu.Show(this, this.PointToClient(Cursor.Position), ToolStripDropDownDirection.Default);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a MouseClick event to notifyicon.
Handle the event as the following:

```
private void NotifyIconClicked(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    _dashboard.ShowHiddenWindow();
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        MethodInfo ShowContextMenu = typeof(NotifyIcon).GetMethod("ShowContextMenu", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        if (ShowContextMenu != null)
        {
            ShowContextMenu.Invoke(_notifyIcon, null);
        }
    }
}
```

I believe the main window has to be made active for this, but I haven't tested this conditional for sure. This is something that i had to implement anyway.

```
    internal static void ShowHiddenWindow(this Window window)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!window.IsVisible)
            {
                window.Show();
            }

            if (!window.IsFocused)
            {
                window.Activate();
            }
            window.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
        }
        catch
        {
            // Avoids "Cannot set visibility while window is closing".
        }
    }
```